# Error merging two PDF files using PDFsharp

Tags: c#, .net, pdf, pdfsharp

I am getting a problem when merging two files. If I try to have the `AddPage(from.Pages[i]);` in a separate void function I get

> An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 
>   It relates to 
>   `CopyPages(one, outPdf);
>   CopyPages(two, outPdf);`

If I make it a static void it will run but the console displays an error stating that it "can not save a PDF with no pages"

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{

    PdfDocument one = new PdfDocument("1.pdf");
    PdfDocument two = new PdfDocument("2.pdf");
    PdfDocument outPdf = new PdfDocument();
    {
        CopyPages(one, outPdf);
        CopyPages(two, outPdf);
        outPdf.Save(out.pdf);
    }

}

void CopyPages(PdfDocument from, PdfDocument to)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < from.PageCount; i++)
    {
        to.AddPage(from.Pages[i]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `one` is an empty PdfDocument, your `two` is an empty PdfDocument, the for loop does nothing, and outPdf is an empty PdfDocument.

As always, the computer does what you tell him to do. You can easily see that if you step through your code in a Debugger.

You have to use something like `PdfDocument inputDocument = PdfReader.Open(file, PdfDocumentOpenMode.Import);` to open a PDF file for import.

See also:
http://www.pdfsharp.net/wiki/ConcatenateDocuments-sample.ashx

`new PdfDocument("1.pdf");` does not open/read a file, it just prepares the creation of a new file with that name.

Comment: I hang my head in shame. Thank you