# PDFsharp does not see pages in documents

Tags: c#, pdfsharp

I made some file merging using PDFsharp before, and now I'm trying to change several files (insert or remove some pages) and I faced with problem, that the library does not see pages. It says that PageCount == 0 and I cannot find pages in object (while debugging). And sure, I cannot do my current work. I use this very simple code:

```
var destinationPdf = new PdfDocument(destinationFilePath);
Int32 count = destinationPdf.PageCount;
```

And also, here is the code, that I used to merge files to one PDF before:

```
public class PdfCreator
{
    private PdfDocument document;

    public PdfCreator()
    {
        this.document = new PdfDocument();
    }

    public void AddImage(String imageFilePath)
    {
        PdfPage newPage = this.document.AddPage();
        XGraphics xGraphics = XGraphics.FromPdfPage(newPage);
        XImage image = XImage.FromFile(imageFilePath);
        xGraphics.DrawImage(image, 0, 0);
    }

    public void AddPdfFile(String pdfFilePath)
    {
        PdfDocument inputDocument = PdfReader.Open(pdfFilePath, PdfDocumentOpenMode.Import);
        Int32 count = inputDocument.PageCount;
        for (Int32 currentPage = 0; currentPage < count; currentPage++)
        {
            PdfPage page = inputDocument.Pages[currentPage];
            this.document.AddPage(page);
        }
    }

    public void AddTextFile(String txtFilePath)
    {
        PdfPage newPage = this.document.AddPage();
        XGraphics xGraphics = XGraphics.FromPdfPage(newPage);
        var xFont = new XFont("Times New Roman", 12, XFontStyle.Bold);
        var xTextFormatter = new XTextFormatter(xGraphics);
        var rect = new XRect(30, 30, 540, 740);
        xGraphics.DrawRectangle(XBrushes.Transparent, rect);
        xTextFormatter.Alignment = XParagraphAlignment.Left;
        xTextFormatter.DrawString(File.ReadAllText(txtFilePath), xFont, XBrushes.Black, rect, XStringFormats.TopLeft);
    }

    public void Save(String destinationFilePath)
    {
        if (this.document.Pages.Count > 0)
        {
            this.document.Save(destinationFilePath);
            this.document.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error merging two PDF files using PDFsharp](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32756544/error-merging-two-pdf-files-using-pdfsharp)

Comment: @ThomasH It seems to be dublicate because the reason for the problem and the solution are the same, but actually, I am sure, that the 'symptoms' are definitely different.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your code

```
var destinationPdf = new PdfDocument(destinationFilePath);
Int32 count = destinationPdf.PageCount;
```

creates a new document in memory - and surely this document is empty.

Use `PdfReader.Open` to create a document in memory from an existing file.

When I place the mouse cursor over PdfDocument in your code I get this tooltip:

> Creates a new PDF document with the specified file name. The file is
>   immediately created and keeps locked until the document is closed, at
>   that time the document is saved automatically. Do not call Save() for
>   documents created with this constructor, just call Close(). To open an
>   existing PDF file and import it, use the PdfReader class.